# <google-map> Want to display floor map with navigation

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Uploading the floor map is clear to me, But I need to implement the indoor navigation (means it displays user current location (blue dot) in the indoor map and the destination path where the user want to reach) in Android. I want to know whether indoor Google navigation is supported in India or not. If it is supported then how to implement it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is supported in India. In fact, you can access Indoor Google Maps  popular indoor venues across 22 cities in [India](https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/1685827?hl=en&ref_topic=1685871).

To implement the geolocation(locating user's position) in your website please use this code:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAAlJFc1lrstqhgTl3ZYo38bBQcfCcww1WgMTxEFsdaTsnOXOVOUhTplLhHcmgnaY0u87hQyd-n-kiOqQ"></script>
<script>
    (function () {
        google.load("maps", "2");
        google.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
            // Create map
            var map = new google.maps.Map2(document.getElementById("map")),
                markerText = "<h2>You are here</h2><p>Nice with geolocation, ain't it?</p>",
                markOutLocation = function (lat, long) {
                    var latLong = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
                        marker = new google.maps.Marker(latLong);
                    map.setCenter(latLong, 13);
                    map.addOverlay(marker);
                    marker.openInfoWindow(markerText);
                    google.maps.Event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
                        marker.openInfoWindow(markerText);
                    });
                };
                map.setUIToDefault();

            // Check for geolocation support    
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                // Get current position
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                        // Success!
                        markOutLocation(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                    }, 
                    function () {
                        // Gelocation fallback: Defaults to Stockholm, Sweden
                        markerText = "<p>Please accept geolocation for me to be able to find you. <br>I've put you in Stockholm for now.</p>";
                        markOutLocation(59.3325215, 18.0643818);
                    }
                );
            }
            else {
                // No geolocation fallback: Defaults to Eeaster Island, Chile
                markerText = "<p>No location support. Try Easter Island for now. :-)</p>";
                markOutLocation(-27.121192, -109.366424);
            }
        }); 
    })();
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have to implement indoor positioning in Android application. Could you please tell me which API i have to use for navigation in Google Map?

Comment: You can insert this code to your backend files on whatever API you are using.

The indoor positioning is a bit complicated. Based on Google Maps, 'After uploading a floor plan, you can help improve the location accuracy for everyone visiting your floor using the Google Maps Floor Plan Marker app on your Android phone. Your new floor plan will appear on your list of floor plans in the Marker app within 24 hours after uploading. Use your phone to improve location accuracy for places you’ve uploaded by walking through the building and collecting relevant location information along the way.'

Comment: @Neeraj, you should also consider this ten things:
1. GPS does not work well indoors
2. Some indoor positioning solutions work similar to GPS
3. Other solutions use light or magnetic fields to determine location
4. RFID and inertial systems work very differently
5. Indoor positioning detects the location of a person or object, but not always its orientation or direction

Just check it all here:

http://www.directionsmag.com/entry/10-things-you-need-to-know-about-indoor-positioning/324602